# If mutiplication of probabilities of two events is equal to their intersection,then are the events always independent?

Tags: probability

Here is an example ,

Let a
ball be drawn from an urn containing four balls, numbered $1, 2, 3, 4$. Let $E =
\{1, 2\}$, $F = \{1, 3\}$ If all four outcomes are assumed equally likely,then we have $P[E \cap F] = (1/4) = P[E]P[F]$.

but intuitively , if I have 1 , than I am certain that F has happened.so probability of E is affecting F. So , are the two events E and F  independent as their products equal their intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are independent.  I think the problem with your intuition though is that when you know $E$ has occurred, you really only know the result is $1$ or $2$.  In this case, things balance out so you end up not having any information about $F$.  And what I mean by that is you can't use the information of knowing $E$ occurred to guess $F$ any better than an individual who has not observed anything: $$P(F|E) = P(F)$$

If you consider the events $E=\{1\}, F=\{1,3\}$ then knowing $E$ really does tell you something about $F$.

Comment: Then , if we add another event G={1,4} , Now , can you please explain how , EFG got dependent ? I mean , E and F are independent, so should be EFG . right ?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have $E$ and $F$ be independent, but individually dependent on $G$.  If you are more familiar with normal random variables this is like saying  $E$ and $F$ can be uncorrelated, yet both be correlated to $G$.  If for example $G$ was $\{1\}$ then $G$ tells you something about $E$ and $F$ but $E$ and $F$ are still independent.

Comment: Hmm, are you asking for an intuitive reason why$P(EFG) \neq P(E)P(F)P(G)$ (with $G=\{1,4\}$)?  If so, that's basically because knowing any two tells you what the outcome was, hence the third.  So then $P(E|FG) \neq P(E)$.

Comment: I see , if FG has happened , then this must be 1, and so E must have happened . Thanks..